# How to see what programs are using keyboard

Tags: keyboard, command-line

Is there a way to find which program uses the keyboard to input stuff?

Why I am asking this question is because my laptop (MacBook Pro) keeps inputting 0 key, my lap works fine after 5 mins from login and this happens all the time, I tried to run a command that disables the keypad but, it doesn't solve the problem, so I concluded that this was a virus, so please help me on this.

Comment: Are you sure there is nothing stuck in the keyboard? Does it happen for all users on your Mac (create a new one to try) or only for a specific one?

Comment: i am 100% sure that nothing is stuck in the keryboard and as i said i have tried disabling the keyboard

Comment: Nevertheless can you try with another user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for wasting your time it was a keyboard problem